# Path is correct but images are not showing?

Tags: php, html

Hi I am trying to show side bar images which is in PHP  from Include folder into PHP page but images are not showing on my page.

sidebar.php is used in other php files too which are present in root directory and for root directory files side.php images are working fine, only **it gives me error in  root-->folder-->newfile.php (here i include my side bar.php)**

**Root Directory --**

include folder ---> sidebar.php

img --->me1.png

unesco-weltkulturerbe-suedafrika-reisen folder ---> abc.php

**Sidebar.php**

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <nav class="social">
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#"><img src="img/me1.png" width="18">Tell: 02241-9424211 </a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><img src="img/me2.png" width="18">Fax: 02241-9424299 </a></li>
              <li><a href="mailto:afrika@bct-touristik.com"><img src="img/me3.png" width="18">afrika@bct-touristik.com </a></li>
              <li><a href="kontakt.php"><img src="img/me4.png" width="18">Kurze Mitteilung o. Rückruf</a></li>
              <li><a href="katalog-bestellung.php"><img src="img/me5.png" width="18">Katalogbestellung</a></li>
              <li><a href="anmeldung.php"><img src="img/me6.png" width="18">Reiseanmeldung</a></li>
              <li><a href="alle-reisen.html"><img src="img/me7.png" width="18">Übersicht alle Reisen</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

**abc.php**

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Side menu widget  -->
    <?php include('includes/sidebar.php'); ?>

    <!-- Header includes menu too -->
    <?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>

    <div class="container-fluid about-inner">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h2>Das Weltkulturerbe und Weltnaturerbe in Südafrika</h2>
                        <ul class="breadcrumb">
                            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                            <li>Das Weltkulturerbe und Weltnaturerbe in Südafrika</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Any paths not starting with a `/` will look in a folder relative to the directory you're currently working in. So if your URL is `http://localhost/unesco-weltkulturerbe-suedafrika-reisen folder/abc.php`, then it will look in `unesco-weltkulturerbe-suedafrika-reisen folder` for the img folder. Start all images with `/` and it will start looking for `img` in the document root

Comment: but my img location is used in other files too which are located in root directory and for which img directory working fine

Comment: yes because `root/img/` is a dir `root/unesco-weltkulturerbe-suedafrika-reisen/img/` is not.  If the file is in `root` then `img/` is relative to that.  So just use `/img` so that it is always relative to `root`.

Answer (score 0):

You are displaying all images in the form

```
img/me1.png

img/me2.png

img/me3.png

img/me4.png

img/me5.png

img/me6.png
```

This will not work at all because img is a subfolder and images are not in root directory. Use this form instead:

```
/img/me1.png

/img/me2.png

/img/me3.png

/img/me4.png

/img/me5.png

/img/me6.png
```

The images should load now.